# MarkdownPad Crashes on Windows 10

Tags: markdown

After upgrading to Windows 10, MarkdownPad 2 no longer functions. The preview window crashes on startup with "Awesomium" error.

I've seen no new activity after submitting a bug report over a week ago. I did see some comments about installing the Awesomium SDK and did try this route, but this installs 2 additional programs (which require separate management/uninstall), so I'm not liking this option.

Has anyone managed to get MarkdownPad to work on Windows 10 and if so, how?

Answer (score 17):

See [Markdownpad2's FAQ](http://markdownpad.com/faq.html#windows10%20%22Markdownpad2's%20FAQ) under problems with Windows 10 technical preview.  Which directs you to what to do with awesomium problems with Windows 8.  Their suggestion, download Awesomium.  They provide the link there.  I tried it.  It worked.

Comment: Thanks for the info.  Per my original question's concerns, I will wait until it's fixed without having to jump through these hoops

Comment: Tried it. Works. However, the Awesomium SDK is a hefty download.

Comment: @mkoertgen there are some good alternatives, eg have a look at [Haroopad](http://pad.haroopress.com/) and [Minimalist Markdown Editor](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/minimalist-markdown-edito/pghodfjepegmciihfhdipmimghiakcjf).

Comment: Thx a lot. Minimalist Markdown Editor is a chrome app! So it's a no-brainer to use chrome for side-by-side html preview. How cool is that

Comment: So as an end-user I need to install an SDK? That's awseless.

Comment: There's also MarkPad in the Store.

Comment: Their instructions did not work for me on Windows 10.

Comment: I finally switched to Haroopad. It was a relief to get rid of the very slow MarkdownPad.

Comment: It's ridiculous you have to install an SDK to get it working. It's still not fixed. I'm not going to install a full blown SDK to get an application working.

Comment: After installing the SDK copy the files from the folder `C:\Program Files (x86)\Khrona LLC\Awesomium SDK\1.6.6\wrappers\Awesomium.NET\Assemblies` (minus Packed and README) into the Markdownpad program directory. After that you can uninstall the SDK again. Or better install the SDK into a VM and throw the VM away after getting the files.

Comment: @PeterHahndorf's approach fixed it for me. In my case, it was only the `Awesomium.dll` that was needed. Looks like the packed version of the dll doesn't work anymore .Unfortunately, I'm experiencing the bug in an app that I built, not Markdownpad2 and repackaging my app's installer with the replacement adds 14 MB to the installer.

Comment: This article https://chaohershi.github.io/MarkdownPad-Crash-And-Error-Fix/ helped me with this issue, and also with the subsequent GitHub markdown rendering SSL/TLS connection error.

Answer (score 6):

A fix that doesn't require installing the full SDK:

1. Download the SDK
2. Create a target folder (e.g. C:\AwesomiumSDK)
3. In command prompt, run `awesomium_v1.6.6_sdk_win.exe /extract:<target folder>`
4. Open `disk1.cab` in the target folder with a tool like 7-zip
5. Extract and overwite the following files to where MarkdownPad is installed: `Awesomium.dll`, `Awesomium.Core.dll`, and `Awesomium.Windows.Controls.dll`

Answer (score 2):

They answer it in the [FAQ](http://markdownpad.com/faq.html#livepreview-directx) but it is easy to miss because it is specifically for Windows 8. It also works for Window 10 too.

The fix is to install [Awesomium 1.6.6 SDK](http://markdownpad.com/download/awesomium_v1.6.6_sdk_win.exe)

Comment: This is virtually identical to [an answer on Super User](https://superuser.com/a/954092).